# Cross domain session authentication with Node.js, Passport, Backbone

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, passport.js

I am using Node.js with express server, and passport package for authentication. Client is on same server, different domain built on Backbone.js. The session is created on login request, but if another request comes from client side, I don't manage to access the session.

Node server configuration:

```
var express = require( 'express' ), 
    path = require( 'path' ),
    mongoose = require( 'mongoose' ), 
    passport = require('passport'), 
    cors = require('cors');

app.configure( function() {
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.bodyParser()); 

    app.use(express.session({ 
        secret: secret,
        key: key,
        cookie : {
            maxAge: maxAge
          }
            })); 

    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session()); 
    app.use( express.methodOverride() );

    app.use( app.router );
    app.use( express.static(application_root) );

    app.use(cors());
});
```

Logging in and auth check:

```
app.post('/login', cors(corsOptions), passport.authenticate('login', {
    successRedirect : successDirect, 
    failureRedirect : failureDirect
}));

function requireAuth(req, res, next) { 
    if(req.session.user) {
        next();
    }
    else if (req.cookies.isAuthenticated) {
        next();
      } else {
       res.redirect(loginUrl);
      }
    }
```

On login, the session is created. If I send any requests from the server side (localhost:9999/anymethod), then the session is accessed, responses accordingly. If I try to send a request from client side to the same url, then the session is always 'undefined'.

Example:

```
app.get('/mymethod', cors(corsOptions), requireAuth, function(request, response) {
    return response.send("Done");
});
```

This method works when accessed from server after logging in, but not when accessed from client side (client is established on same server, different domain).

Added to Backbone.js:

```
 initialize: function() {
        this.collection.fetch({reset: true, beforeSend: this.beforeFetch}); 
    },
    beforeFetch: function(xhr) {
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
    },...
```

Edit: The request coming from client doesn't contain any cookies.

How can I access the session created by passport after logging in, sending a request from client?

Answer (score 0):

I guess cors library does it (i haven't used that library). But if it doesn't then in server side

```
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
 });
```

And in client ajax request

```
 xhrFields: {
     withCredentials: true
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Sami. I added the addition to the client side. The result is still empty. I don't quite understand, from where should the session/cookies be added to the request that comes from the client.

Comment: did u try putting server code also res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

Comment: Yes, the package 'cors' is handling this, credentials are allowed. It seems to me that server hasn't passed any cookies to the client after logging in. Should the passport package handle this?

Comment: No its the job of express session. And as you said if you can access session variable from server and not from client I guess it should be related with CORS

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation @Sami. I for some reason thought that express is setting up the session only on the server side, and that I have to do something additional to receive the session in the cookie to the client side (since it's different domain). The problem is that after the log in, on the client side, there are no cookies/sessions (checked from browser settings), meaning that there are no cookies to send. The question - how to pass the cookies to client OR how to access the cookies on server despite of the request cookies from the client?

Comment: U should have some cookie in client ( check from the chrome inpspect resources cookies) because you are setting up cookie in session.

Comment: Checked it from Chrome - The request doesn't have any cookies. That's the problem - I can't seem to manage to pass the cookies to client. The session/cookies is set up only in server. I can see the cookie with Chrome on server side. But the client doesn't have any cookies set, and therefore the request from client is completely empty from any cookies. The issue doesn't seem to be accessing the request of client, but rather "setting up" cookies for client, and then, sending them to server with a new request. Currently, express is only setting up those for server side.

Comment: @stubgo stubgo, what was the solution here. I am in the EXACT situation 8 years later!

Comment: @Ric Unfortunately I have no memories of the solution (if I ever found one), sorry!